# Using Polymer 0.9.2 paper-drawer-panel doesn't scroll

Tags: html, css, polymer

I am using Polymer 0.9.2 using following `body` tag. However, the `paper-header-panel` will not scroll and even setting CSS to `overflow:scroll`, I get scroll bars but no scrolling.

```
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
<paper-drawer-panel>
    <paper-header-panel drawer>
        <paper-toolbar>
            <div><img src="my-image.png"></div>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <paper-menu id="mainMenu">
            <paper-item>One</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Two</paper-item>
        </paper-menu>
    </paper-header-panel>
    <paper-header-panel main>
        <paper-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div>My Title</div>
            <img src="my-avatar.png" aria-label="avatar" title="avatar" width="64px" height="64px"/>
            <a href="/logout" aria-label="Logout" title="Logout">Logout</a>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <div id="content">My content/div>
    </paper-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
</body>
```

The css that I'm using

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto',Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #4B8A4B;
    background-color: #001900;
}

[main] paper-toolbar {
    background-color: #004C00;
    color: #001900;
}

[drawer] a {
    width: 100%;
}

[drawer] paper-toolbar {
    height: 265px;
}

[drawer] paper-toolbar div {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

[drawer] {
    border-right: thin #000 inset;
    -moz-border-right-colors: #000;
    background: #001900;
}
```

Please not that I have cut out a bunch of extra code that shouldn't impact this problem and I know 0.9 is still Beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `paper-header-panel` is filling the page.

This should be enough to make your content scrollable:

```
paper-header-panel { 
    height: 100% 
}
```

Comment: Needed to do that for `html,body,paper-header-panel`. Though using `fullbleed layout vertical` makes it so that I don't need to do that height trick. At least in 0.5. Ref: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html

Comment: I forgot to import Polymer/layout to get it to work. Added a more complete answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using polymer ~0.5:

```
<body layout vertical>
</body>
```

If you are using >0.8:

```
<body class="layout vertical">
</body>
```

or with CSS (works for any version that I know of):

```
paper-header-panel { 
    height: 100% 
}

body, html {
    height: 100%
    margin: 0
}
```

If you are using the "layout" versions, you must import [Polymer/layout (0.5 docs)](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html) for your version of Polymer.